# Prevent element's text wrapping in grid cell without element exceeding cell's width

Tags: html, css, css-grid, responsive

I have a button inside a grid cell whose size is determined by font-size as `em` and padding as percentage.

I require the text of the button to not wrap.

Initially, I used `<button type="button" id="log_out_button" data-action="manual_log_out">log out</button>` but this produced an undesired result - it wrapped the text:

```
log
out
```

I added `white-space: nowrap` to the button to fix this but it made the button exceed its parent by 0.5cm, which decentralises my grid by the same amount.

To try fixing this knock-on problem, I changed the button to `<input type="button" value="log&nbsp;out" id="log_out_button" data-action="manual_log_out">`, to no avail.

I added `box-sizing: border-box` to the button, to no avail.

I experimented with `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` (third value), trying the various options listed Chrome's dev console, to no avail.

Prior to the navigation being a grid, it was a flexbox that had the same problem.

I want my site scalable so I can't set fixed values i.e. in pixels, and setting the percentage of the cell (grid-template-columns) still results in an offset/decentralisation.

How do I prevent my 'log out' button's text from wrapping *and* prevent it from exceeding its parent's width, such that I avoid the grid's decentralisation issue?

Problem code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 1.5vh;
        }

        header {
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 10.9%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        nav {
            margin: auto;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            grid-gap: 2.5%;
        }

        nav a, nav a:visited {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        #user_identity {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-flow: column;
            align-items: flex-end;
        }

        #navigation_menu_wrapper {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #navigation_menu {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #navigation_menu div {
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            font-size: 1.125em;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: rgb(205, 255, 205);
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(157, 189, 157);
        }

        #navigation_menu a {
            display: block;
            padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #log_out_wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #username_label {
            font-family: "Optima Bold";
            font-size: 1.87em;
            color: rgb(72, 160, 72);
        }

        #permanent_id_label {
            font-size: 1em;
            color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: 9px;
            cursor: default;
        }

        #mobile_menu_control {
            display: none;
        }

        #log_out_button {
            padding-top: 7%;
            padding-bottom: 8%;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background-color: #8dc49d;
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 12%;
            padding-right: 12%;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <div id="user_identity">
                        <div id="username_label">texthere</div>
                        <div id="permanent_id_label">#texthere</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navigation_menu_wrapper">
                        <button id="mobile_menu_control">menu</button>
                        <div id="navigation_menu">
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link1.php">link1</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link2.php">link2</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link3.php">link3</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link4.php">link4</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link5.php">link5</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="../pages/link6.php">link6</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="log_out_wrapper">
                        <input type="button" value="log&nbsp;out" id="log_out_button" data-action="manual_log_out">
                    </div>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <div id="content_wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't with CSS. You need javascript

Comment: You seem to be looking for *FitText* capabilities. Available for jQuery, but here's a vanilla JS version [Codepen: Pure CSS FitText](https://codepen.io/hans/pen/WxBZoQ). Just a few lines of JS. (The pen does use jQuery, but that is easily converted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by commenters, applied the following jQuery/JavaScript fix:

```
logOutButtonWidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    centraliseHeader();
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        centraliseHeader();
    });
});

function centraliseHeader() {
    logOutButtonWidth = $("#log_out_button").outerWidth();
    $("nav").css({
        gridTemplateColumns: "auto auto " + logOutButtonWidth + "px"
    });
}
```